# laravel 5.6 related models to related models softdeletes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Tengo en el modelo Finca.php

```
public function piscinas(){
    return $this->hasMany(Piscina::class)->select('id' , 'finca_id', 'area' , 'name');
}

public function getPiscinasPlanificadasAttribute(){
        return $this->hasMany(Piscina::class)
            ->leftJoin('planificaciones', 'planificaciones.piscina_id', '=', 'piscinas.id')
            ->select('piscinas.id' , 'piscinas.finca_id', 'piscinas.area' , 'piscinas.name' , 'planificaciones.created_at as planificacion_created_at' , 'planificaciones.precio_larva' , 'planificaciones.densidad' , 'planificaciones.id as planificacion_id')
            ->whereNotNull('planificaciones.piscina_id')
            ->whereNull('planificaciones.deleted_at')
            ->get();
    }

public function getPiscinasSinPlanificarAttribute(){            
        return $this->hasMany(Piscina::class)
            ->leftJoin('planificaciones', 'planificaciones.piscina_id', '=', 'piscinas.id')
            ->select('piscinas.id' , 'piscinas.finca_id', 'piscinas.area' , 'piscinas.name')
            ->WhereNull('planificaciones.piscina_id')
            ->get();
    }
```

Y en el modelo Piscina.php

```
public function finca(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Finca::class);
}

public function planificacion(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Planificacion::class);
}
```

Funciona de maravilla, el problema es que al usar softdelete, al eliminar la planificacion de una piscina queda el registro en la tabla planificaciones, posteriormente si deseo agregarle una nueva planificacion a la piscina, no me aparecen las piscinas_sin_planificar, obviamente porque ya piscina.id ya no es null, existe en la tabla "planificaciones" pero con el campo deleted llenado.

existe alguna forma de volver a traerme las piscinas_sin_planificar?

Answer (score 0):

Pues al parecer sólo tienes que agregar un `whereNull`a tu método `getPiscinasSinPlanificarAttribute()`

```
public function getPiscinasSinPlanificarAttribute(){            
    return $this->hasMany(Piscina::class)
        ->leftJoin('planificaciones', 'planificaciones.piscina_id', '=', 'piscinas.id')
        ->select('piscinas.id' , 'piscinas.finca_id', 'piscinas.area' , 'piscinas.name')
        ->WhereNull('planificaciones.piscina_id')
        ->WhereNull('planificaciones.deleted_at')
        ->get();
}
```

Así traerás sólo las que tengan planificación pero que no esté borrada.

Comment: No me trae ningun registro

Comment: Edite la respuesta, lo correcto era `->WhereNull('planificaciones.deleted_at')`